# Define SelectionChanged event using C#

Tags: c#, combobox, selectionchanged

I'm trying to define entirely a combobox using C#, however, I got stuck when I want to code the SelectionChanged event.
This is what I've got so far:
`ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();`
`cmb.Widht=75;`
`cmb.Margin = new Thickness(20,20,20,20);`
`cmb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;`
`cmb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;`
`cmb.SelectionChanged(cmb,cmb_SelectionChanged);`???????
`aGrid.Children.Add(cmb);`
`private void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){ }`
Any idea about what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean from Stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
cmb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmb_SelectionChanged);
```

Regrads

Comment: Thank you! Very fast answer :)